# How to connect Apple TV with Mac for development?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

What kind of cable do I need to connect to the `Apple TV` with my Mac to deploy the app using lightning cable - like I do with iPhone. In the keynote presentation it looks like it's lightning port:

[image: Keynote picture]

And this is what I have, the icon is different - `USB`:

[image: Our Apple TV]

So the question is how to connect to `Apple TV` to deploy an app?

Comment: The USB port on the Apple TV is a USB Type-C port. So you need a USB Type-C cable to connect it to your mac!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not actually a lightning port in the picture, it's a `USB-C` port. To connect the `AppleTV` to your laptop you'll need a `USB-C` to `USB-A` cable, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusion after googling what type of plug would fit in this hole :)

Comment: Not sure I should ask this as a separate question but: has anyone used any  3rd party cables with the appletv? Is there anything special about the apple one?

Comment: As far as I can tell it's just a standard cable.

Comment: I've used a third party cable and it worked wonderfully. Actually, the only Apple USB-C cables for sale are for connecting peripherals to the new 1-port Macbook, and they have the wrong 'gender' on the USB-A end, so you can only buy from third parties. Some devs from the first round of Dev Kits got one cable in the box (so I assume there exist Apple branded ones), I got in during the second round and there was no cable, so I had to buy a 3rd party one.